# Trying to understand use of escape character \ in an -exec clause

Tags: command-line

Here is an example command where I'm trying to understand the function/necessity of the escape symbol "":

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec wc '{}' \;
```

What is in danger of being expanded by the shell without the forward slash near the end there? Is the semicolon that ends the -exec clause the character that is being escaped, or does the \ play some other role? I haven't encountered this command structure before.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: The `\ ` character inverts the "specialness" of the following character. In your case, it makes the shell treat `;` as a regular character (rather than the shell's end-of-statement), and simply put it in `find`'s `argv` array.

Comment: thank you both, those are both helpful answers. I tried searching for a like question but didn't find one, whereas steeldriver found something very analogous and fleshed out in thought. How did you find that?